# removing rows that have same information regardless the order in python Data Frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame that contains two columns I want to remove all duplicated regardless of the order

```
col1     col2
 A        B
 B        A
 C        D
 E        F
 F        E
```

The output should be

```
col1       col2
 A           B
 C           D
 E           F
```

I have tried using the duplicate function but it did not remove anything because they are not in the same order

Answer (score 1):

One way:

1. Take the inner `numpy array` and `sort` it.
2. Use the `dataframe constructor` to recreate the `dataframe(sorted by row)`.
3. `Drop` the `duplicates`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values), columns = df.columns).drop_duplicates()
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
 col1 col2
0    A    B
2    C    D
3    E    F
```